# Given a surjection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{P}(X)$, how can one construct an injection $X\to\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: set-theory

I'm proving that $|X|\leq^*\mathbb{N}$ iff $\mathbb{N}\leq\mathcal{P}(X)$. One direction is trivial, but I'm not sure how to proceed for the other direction. Any suggestions?

***Update***

My apologies. The result as listed above is not necessarily correct, and in any case, not what I was trying to prove. I have made a new post with the relevant changes, here [Given an injection $\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{P}(X)$, how can we construct a surjection $X\to\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139708/given-an-injection-mathbbn-to-mathcalpx-how-can-we-construct-a-surject)

Comment: There is an obvious injection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, but no injection exists $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$....

Comment: Maybe the first inequality should be reversed?

Comment: What does the asterisk on the inequality signify?

Comment: @Dylan: Given the $*$, I suspect that what's wanted is a SURjection from $X$ to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @David: The notation $|A|\le^*|B|$ often means that there is a surjection from $B$ onto $A$.

Comment: Oh, no! I misspoke in the title. I will edit it now.

Comment: You should have just *edited* this post and corrected the mistake, instead of posting an entirely new one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"How to do it" depends on what other things you already know.

Here is a hint: if there is a surjection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $P(X)$, then every singleton subset of $X$ is obtained as $f(i)$ for at least one $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Now I just feel silly for not seeing that. The rest follows rather easily from well-ordering. Seems like an easy generalization to replace $\mathbb{N}$ with any well-ordered set, too. Thanks!