# Dually Dedekind Set and Weakly Dedekind set

Tags: set-theory, definition

$A$ is dually Dedekind infinite (dD-infinite), if there is a surjective non-injective map from $A$ onto $A$.

$A$ is weakly Dedekind infinite (wD-infinite), if there is a surjective map from
$A$ onto the natural numbers.

Q1: Why dD-infinite set are wD-infinite set?

Q2: Why TFAE:
(a) $A$ is wD-infinite set
(b) $\mathcal P(A)$ is Dedekind infinite

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions at once. This makes your question unlikely to be of help for future readers (who are unlikely to have trouble with precisely the same set of questions), and also harder to answer all of them in satisfying detail.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139708/given-an-injection-mathbbn-to-mathcalpx-how-can-we-construct-a-surject is a duplicate for the second question.

Comment: You should probably remove the second question from the post, it was answered in the link I gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f\colon A\to A$ is surjective and not injective, then it has at least one infinite "orbit". Namely, there is at least one $a\in A$ such that $\{x\in A\mid\exists n\in\Bbb Z, f^n(x)=a\text{ or }f^n(a)=x\}$ is infinite.

Assume otherwise, then each "orbit" is finite and closed under $f$. But for finite sets, surjective implies injective. Therefore on every orbit $f$ is injective, and it must be injective in general.

Fix $a$ whose "orbit" is infinite, and simply consider the function:

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} n & f^n(x)=a\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

In essence, this is repeating the proof that $A$ is Dedekind-infinite if and only if there is an injection from $\Bbb N$ into $A$.

Comment: This is the right idea, but is it right to speak about "orbit" when the function is not injective? I don't think I have seen the terminology in this case.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voSpOrimkMY

Comment: what a good proof. Have followed similar argument but was not able to write in such a good way. Thanks